# Jquery twitter feed not returning any results

Tags: jquery, twitter

I was using this code to retrieve twitter feed. It was workign fine but all of a sudden the query stop returning any data. How can I make this work?

Here is the code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function () // don't do anything until the document is loaded.
         {
             $("#submit").click(function (event) { // wire up this as an onclick event to the submit button.
                 var searchTerm = $("#search").val(); // get the user-entered search term
                 var baseUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=";
                 $.getJSON(baseUrl + searchTerm + "&rpp=1500&callback=?", function (data) // call getJSON providing the complete url with search term and a JSONP callback
                     {
                         $("#tweets").empty(); // clear out any previous results.
                         if (data.results.length < 1)
                             $('#tweets').html("No results. Nada. Nuttin. Zippo.");
                         $.each(data.results, function () // iterate over the results, constructing the HTML for the display.
                             {
                                 $('<div align="justify"></div>')
                                     .hide()
                                     .append('<img src="' + this.profile_image_url + '" width="80px" />&nbsp;')
                                     .append('<span><a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + this.from_user + '">' + this.from_user + '</a>&nbsp;' + makeLink(this.text) + '</span>')
                                     .appendTo('#tweets') // append the constructed results HTML to the tweets div
                                 .fadeIn(2000); // fade in the results over 2 seconds.
                             });
                     });
             });
         });

     function makeLink(text) // this REGEX converts http(s) links that are embedded in the tweeet text into real hyperlinks.
     {
         var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
         return text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
     }
</script> 
</HEAD>
<BODY style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%"> 
<div align="center">
<h2>Twitter tag search</h2>
<div>Enter Search Term</div>
<input type="text" id=search />
<input type="button" id=submit value="Search" /> 
<DIV id="tweets" />  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.0 of the Twitter api was deprecated in on June 11, 2013 so the http://search.twitter.com/search.json endpoint will no longer work. You'll need to migrate to version 1.1 which now requires authentication for every request. You can find more information [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#17750).

Comment: How do I go about authentication for every request using jquery and twitter JSON? is there any workign examples i can refer to? Thanks

Comment: You can find a list of libraries on Twitter's developer site [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries). For javascript, I would suggest taking a look at the codebird library [here](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js). The library has several well documented examples.